# Sum and difference formulas for $\csc$ and $\sec$

Tags: trigonometry

We all are familiar with the sum and difference formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$, but is there an analogue for the sum and difference formulas for secant and cosecant?  That is,

$$\csc (A\pm B) = ?$$ and $$\sec (A \pm B) = ?$$

I tried a variation of the sum and difference formulas, but they were incorrect.  Can it be derived geometrically?

Comment: I think you made several mistakes in your derivation.

Comment: Your arguments assert that $$\frac{1}{p\pm q}=\frac1p \mp \frac1q$$  which is untrue. (Try $p=q$.)

Comment: You are correct, Blue.  I will edit my question.

Comment: can you just writ csc and sec in terms of sin and cos, then the obvious answers would reveal themselves.

Comment: also in this case product identities would be more sensible than looking for additive identities.

Comment: I figured as much.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note

$\sin^2 A \cos^2 B -\cos^2 A \sin^2 B\\
= \sin^2 A (1-\sin^2 B )-\cos^2 A \sin^2 B\\
= \sin^2 A - (\cos^2 A + \sin^2 A)\sin^2 B 
= \sin^2 A - \sin^2 B \\
 =\frac12(\cos2B-\cos2 A )\\
$

Thus,

$\csc (A \pm B)
=\frac {1}{\sin A \cos B \pm \cos A \sin B} 
=\frac {\sin A \cos B \mp\cos A \sin B}{\sin^2 A \cos^2 B - \cos^2 A \sin^2 B} 
= \frac {2\sin(A\mp B)}{\cos2B- \sin2 A } 
$

Similarly

$\sec (A \pm B)= \frac {2\cos(A\mp B)}{\cos2B+ \sin2 A } 
$

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-Just simplify $$\left(\frac{1}{\csc(A)\sec(B)}\pm\frac{1}{\sec(A)\csc(B)}\right)^{-1}$$ for sinus and analogue for cosinus.